# why printing the try and catch object is possible altough any normal object isn't

Tags: javascript, object

kindly I am a beginner in JavaScript and i was working on try and catch error handle techniques , until i noticed that the catch object is possible to be printed , but  any normal object isn't for example,

```
   try{
    throw new Error("Manually Thrown Exception");
    }
    catch(errHanlder){
    alert(errHanlder);  // it will give (ERROR:Manually Throw Exception)
    }
```

---

and any created object isn't for example :

```
var obj={name:"User"};
alert(obj);   //it will give [object Object]
```

so why this strange action is possible although the types of both of them are objects

Comment: the answer is the toString method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This object holds a `toString` function.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when
>   the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is
>   referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the
>   toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object.
>   If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString()
>   returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

For errors, it's  [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString).

It's defined in [the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-error.prototype.tostring):

[image]

You can do the same, without even defining it at the prototype level:

```js
 var obj = {name:"Albert", toString(){ return "User: " + this.name }};
 alert(obj);
```

Comment: so that means Error Object overrides the toString method automatically , true ?

Comment: `Error` has a toString method that overrides the (inherited) Object toString method

Comment: @JaromandaX : and when Error overrides .toString() , it make the method  return string , true ?

Comment: the overriding method returns the Error objects `name` property (prepended with "Error:")

Comment: but it is odd that the MDN documentation states that `Error` has no methods, yet it clearly has `toSource` and `toString` in Firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX : that's what i wrote to Ian below , that MDN says no methods , and they wrote methods for this object below in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: @JaromandaX I checked: this method is even defined in the ES standard (see edit)

Comment: @DenysSéguret  : according to MDN ,  the object has methods or not ?

Comment: @mina it has the one of Error.prototype, which overrides the one of Object.prototype

Comment: @DenysSéguret : it's a good time to meet a Senior like you, fully referenced answers with images and mentions from Authorized websites , Really Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `Error` object has the [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function implemented. The result `[object Object]` is printed when an object is lacking a custom `toString()` implementation.

This means if you want to make debugging easier on objects you can implement `toString()` everywhere to get simpler debugging (although many of the Developer Tools sections of browsers do this automatically for you).

Regarding your comment if you read the following [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) you can see that (emphasis mine):

> message is an optional string of text you want to display in the alert dialog, or, alternatively, an **object that is converted into a string** and displayed.

Comment: but i didn't see any official  documentation says that the Javascript automatically calls the .toString Function to convert to string, can you please provide a reference says that does this?

Comment: @user7429498 sure - I've added to my answer for you.

Comment: @user7429498 try console.log({}.toString()) ... same as alert({}) ... most objects will have in their prototype chain a toString method - except if you do something like `var x = Object.create(null)` ... then try alerting x

Comment: @Ian : [Here IN MDN] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) , the documentation says that the object hasn't any methods

Comment: Error inherits from Object ... which has toString method

Comment: @Ian : and accodring to the last edit of you (alert convert object to string by calling toString) ,  so why didn't alert do that with the normal object i made ?

Comment: toString of Object (basically) returns `[object Object]`